# How can I get past CLASSPATH issues and compile the OpenKinect Java Example on OSX?

Tags: java, jar, java-native-interface, kinect

Apologies for posting yet another Java jar question. I did have a look at the existing [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java%20jar%20osx), but still haven't managed to get an [Example](https://github.com/shiffman/libfreenect/blob/master/wrappers/java/OpenKinect/src/Example.java) class running using advices found in existing answers.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
george-profenzas-macbook:src george$ ls
Example.java    org
george-profenzas-macbook:src george$ javac -cp $CLASSPATH Example.java 
george-profenzas-macbook:src george$ ls
Example$1.class Example$2.class Example$3.class Example.class   Example.java    org
george-profenzas-macbook:src george$ java -cp $CLASSPATH Example
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no OpenKinect in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
    at org.openkinect.Context.<clinit>(Context.java:43)
    at Example.main(Example.java:52)
george-profenzas-macbook:src george$ echo $CLASSPATH
/Users/george/Downloads/shiffman-libfreenect-2e0f185/wrappers/java/dist/OpenKinect.jar:.
```

Looks like it didn't find the path to OpenKinect. I tried copying the jar in the same folder(`cp ../../dist/OpenKinect.jar`) then tried running Example again:

```
george-profenzas-macbook:src george$ java -cp OpenKinect.jar Example
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Example
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Example
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Now it seems it didn't find the path to Example, so I assume the `.` in `$CLASSPATH` didn't work and I don't know why.

I kept playing with -cp back and forth but java says "no!":

```
george-profenzas-macbook:src george$ java -cp "OpenKinect.jar:./Example.java" Example
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Example
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Example
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
george-profenzas-macbook:src george$ java -cp "OpenKinect.jar:." Example
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no OpenKinect in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
    at org.openkinect.Context.<clinit>(Context.java:43)
    at Example.main(Example.java:52)
george-profenzas-macbook:src george$ java -cp .:OpenKinect.jar Example
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no OpenKinect in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
    at org.openkinect.Context.<clinit>(Context.java:43)
    at Example.main(Example.java:52)
```

It seems that it either finds the path to the jar, but not to Example or the other way around and I'm running around in circles.
I set the java path to point to 1.6 64bit, so `java -version` prints:

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-384-10M3425)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-384, mixed mode)
```

and I even copied the jar to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Classes` and jnilib to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Libraries`, but no joy.

Any tips ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here is a misunderstanding of the error message. There is a difference between the classpath and the library path. While you got the classpath correct with the jar and the dot for the current directory, you do not specify the path to where the native parts of the Kinect SDK are.

You do so by adding

```
-Djava.libray.path=(path to where the native Kinect libs lie)
```

I do not know the OpenKinect structure, but often it is some kind of "bin" or "native" directory.

To clarify: this is the path where OpenKinect.dll (for Windows) or libOpenKinect.so (Linux and friends) etc. are located.

See http://openkinect.org/wiki/Java_JNI_Wrapper at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: I think that might be it. As you mentioned, there is an OpenKinect.so library so I tried `java -cp $CLASSPATH -Djava.library.path=../../dist/libOpenKinect.so Example` but got `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no OpenKinect in java.library.path
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
 at org.openkinect.Context.<clinit>(Context.java:43)
 at Example.main(Example.java:52)
`

Comment: Only point it to the path, not the .so file, i.e. the dist folder.

Comment: tried that (`java -cp $CLASSPATH -Djava.library.path=../../dist/ Example`), but not much luck :( `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no OpenKinect in java.library.path
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
 at org.openkinect.Context.<clinit>(Context.java:43)
 at Example.main(Example.java:52)
`

Comment: Strange. Put it in the same path as the jar, for a try. Then change to it and give java.library.path as a dot. Maybe the Java code relies on it being in the current dir. Would not be nice, but also not unheard of.

Comment: One more thing mentioned in the OpenKinect wiki page I linked earlier is to become root before trying. It refers to Linux, but maybe trying a "sudo su" first is worth a try.

Comment: I think I'm still doing it wrong :(`
$: ls
Example$1.class  Example$3.class  Example.java  libOpenKinect.so
Example$2.class  Example.class  OpenKinect.jar  org
$: java -cp $CLASSPATH -Djava.library.path=. Example
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no OpenKinect in java.library.path
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
 at org.openkinect.Context.<clinit>(Context.java:43)
 at Example.main(Example.java:52)
` I think I need some fresh air :|

Comment: `sh-3.2# java -cp $CLASSPATH -Djava.library.path=. Example
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Example
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Example
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
` :( time for a break

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5372/discussion-between-daniel-schneller-and-george-profenza)

Comment: I had some time to get back to this issue and didn't get far with the command line, but I did manage to compile and run Example.java after setting up a project in eclipse. Thank you very much for the suggestions.